# Output result from API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

Lately I've started to develop a website. I don't have a lot of experience with web developing, so i hope my question is not too basic.

I have two Ajax functions. One is getting a key and doing something, and the other do the same for all of the keys.

```
function doSomething(key) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/control/doSomething?key=' + key,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $("#doSomething").html(data)
            $("#doSomething").show()
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error')
        }
    });
}
function doAll() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/control/getAll',
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            jsonResult = data['result']

            for (key in jsonResult) {
                doSomething(key)
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error')
        }
    });
}
```

The expected API result of `/control/doSomething/key` looks like this:

```
{
  "host" : "my-pc",
  "ts" : "Tue May 19 15:47:01 2015",
  "status" : "Ok"
}
```

These functions works properly. However, i have an issue with printing the result from the API.  I'm trying to print the output, but nothing happen. I'm just getting an empty blue balloon.

```
<div style="width: 450px;font-size: 14px;margin-top: 50px;display:None" id="doSomething" class="tr-bg tr-internal-frame" onclick='$("#doSomething").toggle()'>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I see, you should:

1. set `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax call options
2. `jsonResult = data['result']` should be `jsonResult = data` (no need of `jsonResult` variable?)
3. `$("#doSomething").html(data)` means you're trying to push a JSON object inside an HTML element. You should thus at least do `$("#doSomething").html(JSON.stringify(data))`, or elaborate your data more.

Comment: Also, if `/control/getAll/` returns *all* the keys, then there's no need to make more AJAX calls to retrieve individual keys, since the `getAll` route should return an array of data.

Comment: @Jack: Thanks. It works. Another question: When i call doAll() i suppose the get many results (For example: ok, ok, error, ok). What should be printed in this case? Can i print each key and the output for each iteration?

Comment: I think it mostly depends on you. You can access the data  via `for(key in data) { /*data[key]*/ }` - as mentioned by @thepanuto, no need to execute the query again.